# Tuple/Float Arithmetic in Python

Tags: python, math, floating-point, tuples

For this simple expression:

```
polyResult = polyResult + poly[len(poly)-1:]
```

I receive a

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'tuple'
```

polyResult is a float, so I tried to convert the tuple value to a float and received the subsequent error:

```
polyResult = polyResult + float(poly[len(poly)-1:])

float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I also tried `polyResult += float(poly[len(poly)-1:])` without success.

Given that the tuple value being called is a float, I don't understand why I am receiving an error that indicates the value is not a number. What am I missing?

Comment: This expression `poly[len(poly)-1:]` extracts the last element of `poly` and wraps it in a tuple. If you're just looking to get the last item of the tuple, try `poly[-1]` instead. Regardless, it would be helpful to see what is stored in `poly`.

Comment: If you're attempting to add a float to each element of a tuple, you have to do that explicitly: `tuple(addend + i for i in my_tuple)`. Which will of course return a tuple of floats, not a single float. (Adding this as a comment, because I don't think that's what you want here; you just want to get the last element of `poly`.)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that when I called from the tuple using the indexing : that the value would arrive in the form of a list. Simply dropping the : ensured that the call returned only the value and the expression was able to resolve.

Comment: What are you expecting of the result. Are you looking for polyResult to be incremented by the sum of the elements of the tuple?

Comment: Thank you abarnert, that is good to know. I will likely need to perform that operation soon so appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Fred, was simply trying to extract the values inside poly and sum them over the course of a loop. That sum is iteratively performing math elseswhere in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably

```
poly[len(poly)-1:]
```

Is slicing out a tuple from the tuple `poly`

Perhaps you meant

```
poly[len(poly)-1]
```

Or more simply

```
poly[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
polyResult += sum (poly)
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.